# Windows phone 7 - Is it possible to use its camera in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to use Windows phone 7's camera in Silverlight in ANY way?

Comment: there is a "windows-phone-7" tag you should use here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a simple code demonstration here showing your to put the camera API to use for Windows Phone 7 apps.

Issues noted from the CTP are since resolved.

[How to: Use Choosers for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769543%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

According to [this post at the MSDN community forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/c29fdab4-e42e-4d63-aadd-de2228fb803b) you cannot access the camera either in Silverlight or XNA.  You can ask the user to take a picture and then access that, but you cannot access the camera directly.

Answer (score 6):

The only way to access the camera is [CameraCaptureTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.cameracapturetask(v=VS.92).aspx). (Note: Unfortunately I don't believe it works in the current Windows Phone Developer Tools CTP.)